# Where does Knoppix store the location of hard drives/

Tags: centos, fsck, knoppix

I've been looking on the web and through the few Knoppix books I have. I cannot see where to locate the hard drives for a CentOS server I've booted with Knoppix.

I am booting the CentOS server with Knoppix, so I can run fsck on the disk. The server hangs during boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all attached drives with

```
$ lsblk
```

or

```
$ fdisk -l
```

Comment: Didn't work for 6.2 Knoppix.

Comment: Strange. But `fdisk -l` should work.

Comment: I'm going to build a newer version of Knoppix. However, 6.2 did boot properly.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. 6.2 is six years old!